# converting an excel program to a python program for pH meter tables

Tags: python, excel, matrix

I study chemistry and we're using pH meters. Our professor gave us a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet which, given a table with ml vs. pH values, plots:

- the sigmoid graph,
- the first derivative graph and
- the second derivative graph.

Since I'd like to have it as an executable program I've decided to code it in python.

In the spreadsheet provided, there are three tables:

1. where you put your data(ml and pH)
2. two columns:

   - the first one (column D) is given by the formula `A3+A4/2`,
   - the second (column E) is given by the formula `(B4-B5)/(A4-A5)`
3. another two columns given by the formulas:

   - `(D3+D4)/2` and
   - `(E3-E4)/(D3-D4)`

[image: pic of the table with example points]

Now, I haven't got any problem creating the first table but then I have to use the formula for the second table and it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?
[image: my code and the terminal output]

Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np

#si crea la tabella dati creando prima la tabella della dimensione corretta con tutti 0 che vengono poi modificati nei dati corretti
tot1 = input("Quante misurazioni sono state eseguite? ")
dati1 = np.zeros((tot1, 2))
for i in range(tot1):
    newml = input("mL=")
    newph = input("pH=")
    dati1[i] = [newml, newph]
print(dati1)
print("\n")

tot2=tot1-2
dati2 = np.zeros((tot2, 2))
for i in range(tot2):
    newml = (dati1[i+1][0]+dati1[i+2][0])/2
    newdelta1 = (dati1[i+1][1]-dati1[i+2][1])/(dati1[1+1][0]-dati1[i+2][0])
    dati2[i] = [newml, newdelta1] 
print(dati2)
print("\n")
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you would paste your code into the question.  It would be a lot easier to read, and people could copy it and try it out.  From what I can make out, you have a divide by zero error at line 17, which means that `dati1[i+1][0]==dati1[i+2][0].`  I don't know what this means in terms of the problem, but perhaps your test data is invalid.

Comment: I've edited the post to make it possible to copy and paste. 
Actually even using real lab points(or actually any set of point that I tried out) it gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line $17$ the first term of the denominator is `dati1[1+1][0]`.  I suspect this is supposed to be `dati1[i+1][0]`

Comment: Thank you a lot, that was actually the problem

Comment: If your problems is resolved you should indicate that by accepting the answer.  That way, it doesn't show up as unresolved.  (And I get a little more rep :).)